# Passing data on another page by clicking the row: It shows that data is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom, mui-datatable

I am using `MUI-Datatable`. And it can already go to the next page, however, no data is showing in History page. How can I fix this?

**Passing data to another page:**

Here, I can see the data in the `console`

```
  const handleRowClick = (rowData, rowMeta) => {
    navigate("/history", rowData[0]);
    console.log(rowData[0], "products");
  };

  const options = {
    filter: true,
    selectableRows: "none",
    responsive: "simple",
    onRowClick: handleRowClick,
  };
```

**History page:**
Nothing shows in the `state`

```
const History = (props) => {
  const { state } = useLocation(); //document ID here
  console.log(state, "state");


  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default History;
```

**App.js**

```
   <Route
            path="/history"
            element={
              <PrivateRoute>
                <Layout>
                  <History />
                </Layout>
              </PrivateRoute>
            }
          />
```

I do not know what is the problem here since I can just pass another data to my `edit-page` whenever I'll click the button `edit` which is present in each row.

Comment: Try like `navigate("/history", {data: rowData[0]})` . You need to add curly braces `{ }` when adding state in route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `navigate` function takes up to two arguments, the "to" target and an "options" object with `state` and `replace` keys.

[useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate)

> ```
> declare function useNavigate(): NavigateFunction;
>
> interface NavigateFunction {
>   (
>     to: To,
>     options?: { replace?: boolean; state?: any } // <-- options object, state
>   ): void;
>   (delta: number): void;
> }
> ```

Move the `rowData` array element into the options object under the `state` key.

Example:

```
navigate("/history", { state: { rowData: rowData[0] } });
```

Use the `useLocation` hook on the receiving component to access the route state.

```
const { state } = useLocation();
const { rowData } = state || {};
```